process.loadEnvFile is not a function
TypeError: process.loadEnvFile is not a function
process.loadEnvFile();


import express, { json } from 'express';

const app = express();
app.use(json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on ${port}`));



Output the code 

how to make the
process.loadEnvFile(); as function  in node js and express js


It's an unstable API added in 21.7, so what version are you using? https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processloadenvfilepath

i have nvm( node virtual machiche ) for this project i m using 21.7.3

@AYUSHRAI It's not reproducible. You can be pretty much sure node version is wrong. Check it with node --version and process.version
